# :Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch) tried all the links but did not help

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle

my **APP.js** code

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: 0x0,

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    web3.eth.defaultAccount=web3.eth.accounts[0]
    // Initialize web3 and set the provider to the testRPC.
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    App.displayAccountInfo();
    return App.initContract();
  },

  displayAccountInfo: function() {
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#account").text(account);
        web3.eth.getBalance(account, function(err, balance) {
          if (err === null) {
            $("#accountBalance").text(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
          }
        });
      }
    });
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('ChainList.json', function(chainListArtifact) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and use it to instantiate a truffle contract abstraction.
      App.contracts.ChainList = TruffleContract(chainListArtifact);

      // Set the provider for our contract.
      App.contracts.ChainList.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      // Retrieve the article from the smart contract
      return App.reloadArticles();
    });
  },

  reloadArticles: function() {
    // refresh account information because the balance may have changed
    App.displayAccountInfo();

    App.contracts.ChainList.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.getArticle.call();
    }).then(function(article) {
      if (article[0] == 0x0) {
        // no article
        return;
      }

      // Retrieve and clear the article placeholder
      var articlesRow = $('#articlesRow');
      articlesRow.empty();

      // Retrieve and fill the article template
      var articleTemplate = $('#articleTemplate');
      articleTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(article[1]);
      articleTemplate.find('.article-description').text(article[2]);
      articleTemplate.find('.article-price').text(web3.fromWei(article[3], "ether"));

      var seller = article[0];
      if (seller == App.account) {
        seller = "You";
      }

      articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text(seller);

      // add this new article
      articlesRow.append(articleTemplate.html());
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
  },

  sellArticle: function() {
    // retrieve details of the article
    var _article_name = $("#article_name").val();
    var _description = $("#article_description").val();
    var _price = web3.toWei(parseInt($("#article_price").val() || 0), "ether");

    if ((_article_name.trim() == '') || (_price == 0)) {
      // nothing to sell
      return false;
    }

    App.contracts.ChainList.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.sellArticle(_article_name, _description, _price, {
        from: App.account,
        gas: 500000
      });
    }).then(function(result) {
      App.reloadArticles();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  },
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

My Truffle.js code

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

i Tried following thigs no use

1) we deleted the build folder completly and

and rerun the

> > truffle migrate --reset

(not succeded )

2) I have used the two commands to check for re compile and deploy no use

> > truffle compile
> >     truffle migrate

(no use)

3) Can anyone explain what this error is saying ? what are artifacts in etherium
**nothing helped me plese help me**

Comment: Hi Venkatesh! To get a potentially more complete answer, please share your deployment code from `migrations` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truffle's default development port is `9545`, like in

```
✗ truffle develop
Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:9545/

Accounts:
(0) 0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57
...
```

In order to deploy locally to Truffle's development environment, try this:

- put 9545 as your port for `development` network
- run `truffle develop` in one terminal
- run `truffle migrate --reset --network development` in another one

Comment: HI 
I am using testrpc  for first testing  it is mentioned it is listing to the port 8545  after running testrpc command  Now if i change the port in the truffle it may cause some issue I think Plese help

Comment: No probs, we'll get to the bottom of it. But please first try the method described above.

Comment: I tried but it is saying rpc error now 
If you don't mind i will give the github link can you downlad and deploy once using testrpc 

https://github.com/chainskills/chainlist/releases/tag/09-buy-contract-end

Comment: Please try describing your trial and error here to let others understand what's happening on your side and come up with a solution collectively - a bit more than "rpc error" could be helpful. It's not like you can say "oh, it doesn't work, go check my code guys" and chill. Well, you can, but it's not the way of StackExchange. Your input is expected to be definitely no less than that from other praticipants, if you want the problem solved. Just tried deploying your code to truffle development network - it's fine, just change the port to `9545`.

Comment: Thanks 

It worked while using metamask and only truffle

Comment: Great! You can deploy in a similar way way to a testnet like Rinkeby. Does this fulfill your development needs and solve the problem?